# The upper bound of $\lim \limits_{n\to\infty} \sum \limits_{i=1}^n e^{-i}\sqrt{i}$?

Tags: limits, summation, upper-lower-bounds

The target is to find the upper bound of the summation.

I can only get that: since $\sqrt{i}<i$,
$$S < \sum \limits_{i=1}^n e^{-i}i = \frac{1-e^{-n}}{e(1-e^{-1})^2} - \frac{n}{e^{(n+1)}(1-e^{-1})}  = T$$

then, we have: $$ \lim \limits_{n\to\infty} T = \frac{1}{e(1-e^{-1})^2} \approx  0.9206735942077925  $$.

I use python to get that S converges to 0.707240718486804.

Does anyone has a more tight upper bound than $\frac{1}{e(1-e^{-1})^2} $? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, it's obvious you can get, for example, $T - (\frac{2 - \sqrt{2}}{e})$. Also may be help that the sum of series is [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) $\operatorname{Li}_\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{e})$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have just heard about Li function but never have learned. I was wondering that: can $Li_{\frac 12}(\frac 1e)$ be represented by some fundamental math symbols? (I guess it cannot because maybe Li function is just like $\pi$ and $e$?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Besides expressing in polylogarithm form, a slightly tighter bound is
\begin{align*}
\left(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} e^{-i}\sqrt{i}\right)^2 &= \left(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} e^{-i/2}e^{-i/2}\sqrt{i}\right)^2 \\
&\le \left(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} e^{-i}\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} e^{-i}i\right) && \text{Cauchy-Schwarz}\\
&= \frac{1}{e-1}T \\
&\approx 0.5358 \\
\implies \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} e^{-i}\sqrt{i} &\le 0.7320
\end{align*}
There are an infinite number of ways to make this bound tighter by simply writing out the first few terms and applying Cauchy-Schwarz on the rest:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} e^{-i}\sqrt{i} &= e^{-1} + \sum_{i=2}^{\infty} e^{-i}\sqrt{i} \\
&\le e^{-1} + \left(\sum_{i=2}^{\infty} e^{-i}i\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_{i=2}^{\infty} e^{-i}\right)^{1/2} \\
&= e^{-1} + \frac{\sqrt{2e-1}}{(e-1)^{3/2}e} \\
&\approx 0.7119
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am wondering that: is it possible to get the exact upper bound by some fundamental math symbols? (I saw $Li_{\frac 12}(\frac 1e)$ representations before.)